# Dynamically adding the input fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have component called `home` having 3 input fields(Country, City, State) as in below  image:

[image]

I am adding input fields dynamically and it's working fine as in below image:

[image]

**But my requirement is:** In the `Country` field instead of `input field`, I  want `dropdown`(select component).But i am unable to do it.
Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-uya7qw?file=app/home/home.component.html)**

Comment: see this is exactly you need: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have every this good in your code, you just need to change your input to [`matSelect`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).

```
<mat-select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.country" name="food">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.value">
    {{country.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-euwpth)

Comment: On adding suppose i want to change the country, Again i need dropdwon.

Comment: @Empty_Soul you mean? I do not understand

Comment: If i want change the country name after adding. I want to go back to 1st set of `input input fields` where i have `dropdown(country)` and 2 `input fields(city, state)` with **add** button.

Comment: I need that dropdown(Country), Even after adding.

Comment: @Empty_Soul I updated my demo link, please have a look

Comment: I got it .Thanks for responce.